# How to create Div and its contents from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a page with a "click" button in it.By click "counter" value increases.

How can I :

1) create json file for my divs like:

```
<div class="text1" id="1">1
    <p>
        content1
    </p>
    <audio src="sounds/audio1.mp3"></audio>
</div>
<div class="text2" id="2">2
     <p>
        content2
    </p>
    <audio src="sounds/audio2.mp3"></audio>
</div>
```

2) find information for the div that has "id" equal to counter

3) create the div on each "click"

http://jsfiddle.net/KFUVq/14/

Comment: the question is one thing and details are the oppossite do you want to create json or read from json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you want to create divs based off of the current counter number.

If that is the case I like to create HTML in jquery with arrays...

so this

```
function createElement(counter){
    var newEl = [
    '<div class="text'+counter+'" id="'+counter+'">' + counter,
         '<p>',
            'content' + counter,
         '</p>',
         '<audio src="sounds/audio'+counter+'.mp3"></audio>',
    '</div>'
    ].join("");
   $("#divToAppend").append(newEl);
}
```

somewhere else

```
createElement(5);
```